# Spring Roo Get role of current logged user

Tags: spring-roo

I am learning about Spring Roo and building a demo application along the way. I am currently focusing on the security provided by `Spring Security` with a database back-end for dynamics.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://roosbertl.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-spring-security-database-in.html) but I can't get to filter the items on `menu.jspx`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are including the Spring JSTL tag libs, you can do something like:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">
```

It works like an "if" that renders the stuff inside the tag when the given user has the specified role.  There are a couple other access methods you can use other than hasRole() as well.  Docs for the JSTL tags are [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html).